# Не выводится изображение. Что делать?

Tags: python, django

Всем привет. Я делаю сайт на Django и у меня почему-то не хочет выводиться картинка.

settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'apps'))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone


class Article(models.Model):
    art_title = models.CharField('Название статьи', max_length = 200)
    art_content = models.TextField('Текст статьи')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Дата публикации')
    image = models.ImageField('Изображение', upload_to = "media/", blank = True)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

app_name = 'main'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name = 'index'),
    path('article/<int:article_id>', views.detail, name = 'detail'),
    path('article/<int:article_id>/leave_comment', views.leave_comment, name = 'leave_comment'),
    path('article/<int:article_id>/delete_comment', views.leave_comment, name = 'delete_comment'),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Article, Comment
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
import django.http as http

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    latest_articles_list = Article.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    return render(request, 'main/list.html', {'latest_articles_list': latest_articles_list})


def detail(reques, article_id):
    try:
        a = Article.objects.get( id = article_id )
    except:
        raise Http404("Статья не найдна(")

    latest_comments_list = a.comment_set.order_by('-id')[:10]

    return render(reques, 'main/detail.html', {'article': a, 'latest_comments_list': latest_comments_list})
```

detail.html

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static 'article.image' %}" alt="{{article.art_title}}">
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте в шаблоне цикл `for` для вывода информации из queryset. Ваше представление передает в шаблон не один экземпляр модели, а несколько, поэтому нельзя просто обратиться к экземпляру через `{{ article.image }}`.

Также, вы загружаете изображения в медиа ресурсы, а пытаетесь получить из их статики

```html
{% for article in latest_articles_list %}
    <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ article.image.url }}" alt="{{article.art_title}}">
{% endfor %}
```

**UPD**: я не увидел, что вы задаете вопрос про detail.html, а не про представление index, мои извинения) Постарайтесь приводить только нужные фрагменты кода, а не весь проект целиком

Решение то же: используйте медиа ресурсы, чтобы вывести изображение:

```html
    <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ article.image.url }}" alt="{{article.art_title}}">
```

Comment: У меня проблема заключается в пути -    <img src="/media/media/0RYR6MCp8m4.jpg" alt="tgedrws">

Comment: Это после использования моего решения? Тэкс, а если убрать {{ MEDIA_URL }}?

Comment: Там прикол в том что не получается прописывать нормальный путь фотографии или сохранять нормально фотографии